# Cargo run ignores the features specified to cargo build

Tags: rust

I've compiled the [Rust GTK examples](https://github.com/gtk-rs/examples) this way:

```
$ cargo build --features gtk_3_10
```

When I try to run the example, an error occurs:

```
   $ cargo run --bin gtktest   
    Compiling gtk-rs-examples v0.0.1 (file:///home/me123/rust/gtk_examples)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.39 secs
     Running `target/debug/gtktest`
This example only work with GTK 3.10 and later
Did you forget to build with `--features gtk_3_10`?
```

How to fix that?

Comment: Just a heads up: You shouldn't need to manually execute `cargo build` before `cargo run`. `cargo run` will take care of building automatically if it needs to, passing the relevant flags you give it along.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the features when calling `cargo run`:

```
cargo run --bin gtktest --features gtk_3_10
```

You could also run the executable directly after building it:

```
$ cargo build --bin gtktest --features gtk_3_10
$ ./target/debug/gtktest
```

You can tell that your command isn't doing what you expect because the output says that your code is being recompiled:

```
Compiling gtk-rs-examples v0.0.1 (file:///home/me123/rust/gtk_examples)
```